# Intel Optane: can't find Optane memory volume

Tags: optane

I bought used 32GB Optane + 512GB Nand Intel Optane H10 NVME drive. My BIOS SATA mode is `AHCI`.

I plan to use Intel Optane with Linux and don't need any special features.
I just want to use `32GB` as usual SSD partition, but I can't see this partition neither in Windows (`Computer management`), Linux (`fdisk -l`) and BIOS. Only `512GB` is visible in all OSes. Is it possible to use Optane stick with AHCI mode? Or here is some hardware issue and Optane partition should be visible in any case?

Also, I tried to set `RST` mode in BIOS. OS becomes unbootable and that is normal, but the weird thing is I can't see `32GB` partition even in `RST` mode. So I can't figure out is Optane part completely hidden from user or is it hardware problem?

`lspci` output is

```
6c:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981/PM983
6d:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Intel Corporation Device 0975 (rev 03)
...
```

where `SAMSUNG` is a primary M.2 drive and Optane is second. So only one `Non-Volatile memory controller` device is shown

My configuration is [ASUS Expertbook B9450FA](https://www.asus.com/us/commercial-laptops/asus-expertbook-b9450fa/tech-specs/)

---

Finally I removed `SAMSUNG` drive and inserted `Optane` drive into primary slot.

After that completely switched to `RST with Premium Optane Acce...` blah blah blah mode (don't remember exact term) in BIOS
Installed fresh Windows 11, drivers and RST CLI.

Here is output of CLI:

```shell
c:\Users\user\Downloads>RstCliPro.exe --OptaneMemory --progress

DEVICE_STATE_INVALID: Request is not supported with the current device state.

There is no Optane Volume

Error code: 0x0

c:\Users\user\Downloads>RstCliPro.exe --OptaneMemory --info

Controller: Intel(R) Chipset SATA/PCIe RST Premium Controller \\Scsi0 --
Intel Optane Memory is not enabled on this Controller

Equipment is not Intel Optane ready because
             CPU: Supported
             PCH: Supported
Operation system: Supported
  Optane feature: Supported

Intel Optane memory module not detected: not present or remapping disabled
```

Looks like Optane Volume is not visible even if RST mode is enabled... Bug or feature?..

PS my intel chip is i7-10510U and according to intel [docs](https://www.asipartner.com/resources/intel-optane-memory-h10-integration-requirements/):

> Intel 10th Generation Core Processor Motherboards ship with an Intel 400 series chipset. All 400 series chipsets except the H410 support the requirement for a bifurcated M.2 PCIe x4 slot where the slot is divided through BIOS to allow for one PCIex2 for the SSD and one PCIex2 for the Optane cache to support the Optane H10

what is a kind of positive news...

Comment: No; You cannot it requires Intel RST to be enabled, which to my knowledge has zero Linux support.

Comment: @Ramhound and then what is this: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000032993/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-persistent-memory.html ? And is this wrong: https://codenotary.com/blog/ubuntu-how-to-use-intel-optane-memory-for-ssd-caching ?

Comment: What is the output of `lspci`? That should tell you if the device is two devices in one.

Comment: @Mokubai I added info to question

Comment: Do you have an Intel or AMD motherboard? https://forum.level1techs.com/t/does-optane-h10-show-up-as-2-drives-on-x470/173487/6 suggests that seeing both parts requires the motherboard to support splitting the x4 slot into two x2 ports, which not all motherboards will.

Comment: @Mokubai Added info in question: Asus Expertbook B9. Hmmm... not sure how to check is my device support splitting (probably not)

Comment: It looks like your laptop has two NVMe slots. It might be that optane will only work in one of those two slots, can you change which slot that drive is in?

Comment: And, it's also good idea to try to start the laptop with only one NVMe slot populated

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov  `try to start the laptop with only one NVMe slot` -> tried. Added info in question

Comment: @Mokubai `can you change which slot that drive is in` -> Yep. Tried. See result in question. Now my PC is theoretically Optane ready and I able to run any command (However, no Linux now :( )

Answer (score 1):

I tried all ways how to determine Optane Memory without any luck:

1. activate RST in BIOS
2. install many versions of [drivers](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19512/intel-rapid-storage-technology-driver-installation-software-with-intel-optane-memory-10th-and-11th-gen-platforms.html) (v16..., v17..., v18...)
3. install multiple software ([1](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19462/782083/intel-rst-cli-pro-for-intel-optane-memory.html), [2](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/download/19543/intel-memory-and-storage-tool-gui.html), [3](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9MZNG5HZWZ1T)) to check if memory exists (and it does not exist)

According Intel [support page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000035106/memory-and-storage/intel-optane-memory.html):

> If the device is placed in a system that isn't properly supported, only the Intel® QLC 3D NAND side of the device will be recognized and accessible.

So I decided even if my notebook support RST and Optane technology, the `H10` series is not supported (and no information in the Internet about compatible devices... ridiculous). Or second possible reason - the memory is broken. I think here is compatibility problem. Looks like only desktop motherboards (and laptops with preinstalled `H10` by default) support this memory. So I don't recommend it to anyone. Waste of money and time.